# Batch file-download script - is it necessary to re-phrase commands?

Tags: optimization, batch

I run a script to download a file and unzip it. An import process then runs and leaves the files in their source location. I wrote the fully functioning code below to clean up that directory to be ready to use the next night.

I streamlined as much as I believe possible. I realize ~15 lines of code isn't exactly verbose or complicated and I've included the full script for reference. I feel, however, that specifically the second block - line `SET DATE=` through line `DIR` - can be better written but I don't know in what way. Am I simply seeing messy code where none exists?  It just doesn't seem to 'read' well.

A note - the index.txt file is the same despite having two paths and is located in one or the other depending on the outcome (errors or not) of the import.

```
SET PATH="\\server\path\path2"
IF NOT EXIST %PATH%\Upload.zip GOTO Done

SET DATE=%date:~4,2%-%date:~7,2%-%date:~10,4%
MKDIR %PATH%\Archives\%date%
SET ARCHIVE=%PATH%\Archives\%date%\
DIR %PATH% /B > %ARCHIVE%log-%date%.txt

MOVE %PATH%\Upload.zip %ARCHIVE%Upload-%date%.zip
MOVE %PATH%\index.txt %ARCHIVE%index-%date%.txt ||(
MOVE %PATH%\error_files\index.txt %ARCHIVE%index-%date%.txt
)
DEL %PATH%\*.tif
RMDIR %PATH%\error_files

PUSHD %PATH%\Archives &&(
FORFILES /S /D -15 /C "CMD /C IF @isdir == TRUE RD /S /Q @path"
) & POPD

:Done
```

Comment: I think `&` separates two commands. Regarding the last lines: Is  there a difference between 
`command1 && (command2) & command3` and `command1 && (command2 & command3 )` and `comman1 && command2 & command3` ?
When will `command3` be executed?

Comment: I used an existing snippet to create that and more recently began to understand it. As such, I am still questioning the use of `&&` as opposed to listed three separate commands. I realize it will run `command2` and `command3` only if `command1` is successful, but I can't think of an instance where `PUSHD` would fail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think there's a better way to format your `%DATE%` variable. And be careful, because I think this won't work in all locales. I had this problem a few years ago, and I remember that there was no good solution to format dates using native commands. I had to make a simple `dateformat` utility myself to generate date formats easily and in a locale independent way.

Just a small thing, I recommend NOT to put the trailing `\` in the `%ARCHIVE%` variable. So instead of this:

> ```
> SET ARCHIVE=%PATH%\Archives\%date%\
> DIR %PATH% /B > %ARCHIVE%log-%date%.txt
>
> MOVE %PATH%\Upload.zip %ARCHIVE%Upload-%date%.zip
> ```

Write like this:

```
SET ARCHIVE=%PATH%\Archives\%date%
DIR %PATH% /B > %ARCHIVE%\log-%date%.txt

MOVE %PATH%\Upload.zip %ARCHIVE%\Upload-%date%.zip
```

This may be a matter of taste, but I like to see explicitly that it's a *directory* there, not just a *prefix*.

Another formatting tip about this:

> ```
> MOVE %PATH%\index.txt %ARCHIVE%\index-%date%.txt ||(
> MOVE %PATH%\error_files\index.txt %ARCHIVE%\index-%date%.txt
> )
> ```

I find it easier to read when the commands inside `(...)` are indented, like this:

```
MOVE %PATH%\index.txt %ARCHIVE%\index-%date%.txt || (
    MOVE %PATH%\error_files\index.txt %ARCHIVE%\index-%date%.txt
)
```

Comment: I follow the logic regarding the trailing back-stroke - I agree. Looking at the code again, it's also inconsistent with my other variables so I should change for that reason, as well. And the indent! I always forget that - thanks for the reminder.

Answer (score 3):

```
PUSHD %PATH%\Archives &&(
FORFILES /S /D -15 /C "CMD /C IF @isdir == TRUE RD /S /Q @path"
) & POPD
```

is the same as

```
PUSHD %PATH%\Archives &&(
FORFILES /S /D -15 /C "CMD /C IF @isdir == TRUE RD /S /Q @path"
) 
POPD
```

but the latter syntax is simpler
.

Comment: I'll make the update. This piece came from previous code; I never thought to review it. My thinking was "fewer lines are better". But the more I look at it, the latter is easier for other users to understand. Thank you for the direction, the research in to _why_ both options work helps me learn.